# How can I change the text of a DIALOG button after initialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dialog, uibutton

I wrote a dialog definition, but the name of the buttons depend on the situation.
When I open the dialog, I want to set the buttons name.
I can´t find a solution, how to rename a dialog button after define it.
Here is my Dialog Code:

```
     $( "#neueFrage" ).dialog({
     resizable: false,
     autoOpen: false,
     height: 900,
     width: 1100,
     modal: true,
     closeOnEscape: false,
       open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide()},
       buttons     : [{
                          text    : 'SAVE',
                          class : 'dialogbutton',
                          click    : function() {}
                      },
                      {
                          text    : 'CANCEL',
                          class : 'dialogbutton',
                          click    : function() {
                          }
                      }
                  ]    
     });
```

I call the dialog with this small code sample.
If 'Yes', everything is ok, but if not, I want to rename the button to 'REDO'.

```
if ($(this).text()=="Yes") {
    $( "#neueFrage" ).dialog( "open" );
} else {
    //Rename the button 'SAVE' to 'REDO' before open dialog
    $( "#neueFrage" ).dialog( "open" );
}
```

How can I change the button´s name in **else**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
buttons     : [
                          {

                              text    : 'SAVE',
                              class : 'dialogbutton',
                              click    : function() {},
                              id:"savebtn"

                          },
                          {
                              text    : 'CANCEL',
                              class : 'dialogbutton',
                              click    : function() {


                              },
                              id:"cancelbtn"
                          }
                      ]    
         });

if($(this).text()=="Yes"){
  $( "#neueFrage" ).dialog( "open" );    
}else{
$("#savebtn").find("span").text("whatever")
 $( "#neueFrage" ).dialog( "open" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps.  Somehow I didn´t realize, that you can give these buttons IDs.